# Docker desktop uses 7% of CPU while I set it up to use 12/16 processors

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm using docker desktop v4.18.0 with WSL2; my machine has 16 cores, made sure of it by using

```
$totalLogicalCores = (
 (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors |
   Measure-Object -Sum
).Sum
```

I've set up the .wslconfig with `processors=12`, and if I run a linux container, I can see that `nproc` gives `12`.

Now, while running a task, I see 100% usage of the CPU on the docker desktop "stats" tab, while I see only ~7% CPU usage on Windows' Task Manager.
[image][image]

I imagined that since I'm using 12/16 cores, the Task Manager would have shown at least 70% of the CPU, is there something I'm missing here?
Is docker using less CPU than I wanted?

Comment: I have similar problem. Were you able to find a solution for it?